# How to count the number of times a combination appears in a binary table in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a Pandas DataFrame that contains two columns:

1. Combination - contains tuples that describe a combination of products in the binary table (e.g., ("bread", "eggs"))
2. Count - contains the number of times that this combination appeared in the binary table

The binary table that I keep referring to looks like this. 1 just means that the product is in that specific product (or in this case, it is present in the combination), and 0 if otherwise.

```
      bread  cheese  eggs  flour  jam
1000    0      0       1     0     0
1001    1      0       0     0     0
1002    1      0       1     1     0
1003    1      0       1     0     1
1004    0      0       1     0     0
  ...  ...    ...     ...   ...   ...
1495    1      0       1     1     0
1496    1      1       1     0     0
1497    0      0       0     0     1
1498    1      0       0     0     0
1499    1      0       1     0     0
500 rows × 5 columns
```

I already figured out how to create the combinations column, I just don't know how to create the count column using the data from the binary table. Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

combinations_list = []
products = ["bread","cheese","eggs","flour","jam"]

for p in range(2, len(products)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(products, p):
        combinations_list.append(str(subset))

#code for count column here

report = pd.DataFrame(combinations_list,columns=['Combinations']) 
report
```

This is what the code looks like but I still need to add the count column.

```
>>
    Combinations
0   ('bread', 'cheese')
1   ('bread', 'eggs')
2   ('bread', 'flour')
3   ('bread', 'jam')
4   ('cheese', 'eggs')
5   ('cheese', 'flour')
6   ('cheese', 'jam')
7   ('eggs', 'flour')
8   ('eggs', 'jam')
9   ('flour', 'jam')
10  ('bread', 'cheese', 'eggs')
11  ('bread', 'cheese', 'flour')
12  ('bread', 'cheese', 'jam')
13  ('bread', 'eggs', 'flour')
14  ('bread', 'eggs', 'jam')
15  ('bread', 'flour', 'jam')
16  ('cheese', 'eggs', 'flour')
17  ('cheese', 'eggs', 'jam')
18  ('cheese', 'flour', 'jam')
19  ('eggs', 'flour', 'jam')
20  ('bread', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'flour')
21  ('bread', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'jam')
22  ('bread', 'cheese', 'flour', 'jam')
23  ('bread', 'eggs', 'flour', 'jam')
24  ('cheese', 'eggs', 'flour', 'jam')
25  ('bread', 'cheese', 'eggs', 'flour', 'jam')
```

Can anyone please help me? Thank you!

Comment: Can you write the code that gets the rows corresponding to the combination `('bread', 'cheese')`? If you have those rows, can you write code that tells you how many rows there are? If you can do that, can you write code to do that for each combination, as you compute them? If you can do that, can you solve the problem? Where exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: @KarlKnetchel I see what you mean, thank you for your help. I also apologize, I'm really not that experienced with coding and I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but what do you mean by "gets the rows corresponding to the combination ('bread', 'cheese')"? Because I think that's where I'm stuck.

Comment: For example, *should you count* the row `1000    0      0       1     0     0`  for the combination `('bread', 'cheese')` (which means the same thing as "does that row correspond to the combination") when you are trying to figure out that count value? How do you know? Can you write code to figure that out?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do that, I'm sorry :( That's where I'm stuck right now.

Comment: I am assuming you have ```import pandas as pd``` above the ```import itertools``` right? Otherwise you are going to have even more problems, lol.

Comment: @NewCoder18 Yes, I did. I imported it in the cell above. Sorry about that, I'll edit my question.

Comment: I know how to do it with pencil and paper but I don't know how to do it in code. I know that the first row shouldn't count. I just meant that I don't know how to write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
d={}
for x in range(2,len(df.columns)+1):
    for y in itertools.combinations(df.columns,x):
        d[y]=0

for x in range(2,len(df.columns)+1):
    for i in df.index:
        s=[k for k in df.columns if df.loc[i, k]==1]
        p=[j for j in itertools.combinations(s,x)]
        for w in p:
            d[w]+=1

res=pd.DataFrame({'comb':d.keys(), 'count':d.values()})
```

For the visible part of your df (the rows you provided in the question) this code returns:

```
>>>print(res)
                                 comb  count
0                     (bread, cheese)      1
1                       (bread, eggs)      5
2                      (bread, flour)      2
3                        (bread, jam)      1
4                      (cheese, eggs)      1
5                     (cheese, flour)      0
6                       (cheese, jam)      0
7                       (eggs, flour)      2
8                         (eggs, jam)      1
9                        (flour, jam)      0
10              (bread, cheese, eggs)      1
11             (bread, cheese, flour)      0
12               (bread, cheese, jam)      0
13               (bread, eggs, flour)      2
14                 (bread, eggs, jam)      1
15                (bread, flour, jam)      0
16              (cheese, eggs, flour)      0
17                (cheese, eggs, jam)      0
18               (cheese, flour, jam)      0
19                 (eggs, flour, jam)      0
20       (bread, cheese, eggs, flour)      0
21         (bread, cheese, eggs, jam)      0
22        (bread, cheese, flour, jam)      0
23          (bread, eggs, flour, jam)      0
24         (cheese, eggs, flour, jam)      0
25  (bread, cheese, eggs, flour, jam)      0
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so much! Can I ask though why my code is returning different values under the count column? For some reason, the values are 70,156,86,...

Comment: Welcome, happy to help :)
You get different results, because my code is applied only on the rows you provided in the question

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with melt and groupby as well:

**Sample:**

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'bread': {1000: 0, 1001: 1, 1002: 1, 1003: 1, 1004: 0}, 'cheese': {1000: 0, 1001: 0, 1002: 0, 1003: 0, 1004: 0}, 'eggs': {1000: 1, 1001: 0, 1002: 1, 1003: 1, 1004: 1}, 'flour': {1000: 0, 1001: 0, 1002: 1, 1003: 0, 1004: 0}, 'jam': {1000: 0, 1001: 0, 1002: 0, 1003: 1, 1004: 0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

**Code:**

```
df_count = (df*df.columns).reset_index()
df_count = df_count.melt(id_vars='index', value_vars=df.columns)
df_count = df_count[df_count['value'].ne('')]
df_count.groupby(['index'])['value'].apply(tuple).value_counts()
```

**Returns:**

```
(eggs,)                 2
(bread,)                1
(bread, eggs, jam)      1
(bread, eggs, flour)    1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @whitecheddar, your very welcome. If the answer was helpful, please consider upvoting. Happy coding!